# Add a calculation rule to a Sp based on the destination table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes columns from multiple tables something like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
    SELECT
        (B.ColumnBBBB AS Column1, 
         C.ColumnCCC AS Column2, 
         D.ColumnDDDD AS Column3,
         --CASE WHEN A.Column1 ....  AS Column4,
         --CASE WHEN A.Column4=x AND Column3=Y THEN .. ELSE .. AS Column5
    FROM 
        B 
    LEFT JOIN 
        C ON ...=...
    LEFT JOIN 
        D ON ...=...)
```

When I do this I get the following error :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure , Line 212 [Batch Start Line 5]
> The multi-part identifier "A.Column1" could not be bound.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the table definition for A and B? Also do you mean to have SELECT( ?

Comment: Nope - the select statement must stand on its own without reference to the table you are inserting into. If you need to refer to that table, you must join (in some fashion) to it in the select statement.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816402/solve-the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-error-in-sql-server

Comment: @SMor I think it would be better to add those calculation rules in the create table script, what do you think ?

Comment: Impossible to say based on the little information provided. "Calculation" can mean many things. Perhaps a calculated column might work. But without knowing what you calculate and what values are needed to do that, there is no reason to guess. I suggest you simply forget about the insert part of your question and focus on writing the select query that generates the results you need. Kinda pointless to work with an anonymized fragment of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `INSERT.....SELECT`, the `SELECT` knows nothing about the `INSERT`. In other words: you must make sure the `SELECT` can run by itself and present you with the data you want, then you can add the `INSERT`.

You should be suspicious of the way you wrote this, because while you are specifying how tables B,C,D are joined, how would the program know how A is joined with B?

So you must change your 'FROM' to:

```
FROM A
    (INNER?) JOIN B on some_condition
    LEFT JOIN C (...continue with your code)
```